# Facebook graph api not fetching facebook mutual friends

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5

I am trying to get Facebook mutual friends list. Below code is returning my response in proper format and columns.

My code is:

```
public function mutualFriendsList(){
            $bootStrap = '';
            $response = [];
            $current_page = 1;
            $page = '';
            $userPicture = '';
            $offset = 0;
        try{
            if(! $this->userObj){
                $this->error = ($this->error)? $this->error : 'invalid_user';
                return $this->sendResponse();
            }
            $access_token = 'CAAY31tOKqVwBAGWpkElTqCcOrwfaiSFGGZCuLv5qsaGgZAHHoJtZB8ZA1cGnY7sTXDJVl7lyJBVuLJiJ44eIH69ozVNqeMdgYMmgZANrXyMiqUqo0vUeNtrtBKG7ZBmNANgLFsdyilw86Ey74GEjovA764DHPgJlTnZAAdbOBZB04KrZAcLGL7abeWW6H80LsqLgjRAVn5yMvI0iAQxhNiXEC6CIPSKD12LKdOYHiw1H2rgZDZD';
            $access_token2 = 'EAAY31tOKqVwBAERZAINanLu6AGylZALv5VhUKXZCSSC03voKimvJmAWGMVdp8ZA9XtCs2h8TNYEDoJy1uYoZBJAygUlBeZBP5xsukcZBY48XdLZAkAuVFweqgpyvO1xgcHyXGiNrAyQ6ZCoSZBfrqL60qEPYle0jZAQVPaBXULCCLfN70oicpqHXo5M';
            $user_id = '138815893176219';
            $user_id2 = '522861154560277';
            $mutual_array = Facebook::get('/' . $user_id2 . '?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends)', $access_token);  
            $friends = $mutual_array->getGraphUser()->asArray();
            if(isset($pagination['paging']) && is_array($pagination['paging'])){
                $response['paginate'] = true;
            }else{
                $response['paginate'] = false;
            }
                $this->payload = $response['data'] = $friends;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            self::logError($e, __CLASS__, __METHOD__);
            $this->error = "exception";
        } finally{
           return $this->sendResponse();
        }
    }
```

Following is response:

```
"responseCode": 200,
  "response": {
    "context": {
      "id": "dXNlcl9jb250ZAXh0OgGQt0OIRNHzgt4LO4It75TqUZB8rBW9zZBf9EKCkQN6XL47ccL5z8ygrmmtz7rZA1gTmepiuvqQqW4RbcjpuNIlu74ZBwcGvzacMofxFNO7ap17PSgZD"
    },
    "id": "522861154560277"
  }
```

Comment: are you aware that you can only get friends who authorized your app?

Comment: How can i confirm from my app that my app is authorized me to get friends ?

Comment: what? i think you misunderstood, read my comment again. you CAN'T get any friend who did not authorize your app.

Comment: you means i can get only those friends who have authority to get my app ?

Comment: yes, that´s how it is. you can only get friends who are using your app (with the user_friends permission).

Comment: how can i set user_friends permission in the app ?

Comment: read the docs, it´s all in there.